# Connection between phpstorm and xdebug

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I configured phpstorm-xdebug and I was able to debug my code with breakpoints.
These days I updated php (through brew) and xdebug and now I have php 5.5.26 with xdebug 2.3.3.
When I try to debug tests (and code) phpstorm tells me: "connection with xdebug was not established".

I already checked the configuration of xdebug in php.ini and it's as follow

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/local/opt/php55-xdebug/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

and the web server debug validation says

[image]

I tried with different versions of phpstorm, uninstalling e reinstalling php55/php55-xdebug but with no success.

Do you have any idea on how to solve the problem?

Comment: Did you install php_fpm? Did you click on the `Start listening` icon on the top menu bar ? Did you configure your DBGproxy (in tools menu) with the proper IDE key, port, etc ... If you register your DBGproxy and that fails, some process is probably already hijacking the 9000 port.

Comment: Yes I've php_fpm installed but I think I'm using php since I start the tests in the console.
And yes, I added the DBGproxy listening on port 9000 with PHPSTORM as idekey

Comment: if php-fpm (the process) is started, and you did not explicitely configure it (with your apache), it hogs port 9000 by default. try to `killall php-fpm` to see if it is running. Then try to debug again.

Comment: You do not need DBGproxy at all if 1) you are the only one person who does debugging 2) it's local. DBGproxy can be used for remote debug and particularly if you debug over SSH / share the same IP with other devs.

Comment: @AndreaGiuliano How do you debug: via CLI or via browser? Can you please show xdebug section of `phpinfo()` output captured in the same environment as you debug (I mean: if debugging via browser then capture output via browser). Thing is: you may have different php.ini for CLI and web server.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg You're right, I killed php-fpm and debugger now works. But previously kiling php-fpm I tried to change port and nothing changed.
What do you think it could be?

Comment: @AndreaGiuliano Not certain Andrea, when hunting an obscure thing like this it is easy to lose track. I will post my answer in full, for others to benefit from it instead of the MIL-STD-RTFM answer we keep seeing on that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing a new PHP, if you start php-fpm without configuring it properly, it defaults to listen on port 9000. Here is the 'stock' php-fpm.conf from the distro you need to edit:

**/usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php-fpm.conf**

```
...

;   '[::]:port'            - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses
;                            (IPv6 and IPv4-mapped) on a specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

It binds the port 9000, change it to another value (in my case changed it to 8001). Then configure your apache's config accordingly. Here is my config example config (apache 2.4), binding to port 8001

**/usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/extra/proxy-fcgi.conf**

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:8001/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/$1
DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

restart apache and php-fpm, and you are good to go to use port 9000 for xdebug. Start PhpStorm.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to solve it - to change the port of xdebug in php.ini. For example to 9001:

`xdebug.remote_port=9001`

After that you need to change xdebug port in PhpStorm in Preferences->Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug. Xdebug port set to 9001.

Answer (score 0):

Change `xdebug.remote_port=9001` in `php.ini` and `phpstorm` too, work for me.